# Silverlight How to Move Control Between Grid rows?

Tags: silverlight, controls, move

How I can move control from one row of Grid to another **without** remove the control from the first row and then add it to the second row???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do this at run-time, in the code-behind, you can try:

```
// Assuming your control is not in row 1
myControl.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why? To get this done easily, you **have** to change the row that it is in.

Another way is to use math and do calculation of the height of grid, row and control and position it by margin. - very messy code.

Comment: I don't think he's asking what you think he's asking. I interpreted the question as: How can I change the row that a control is in without first removing it from the grid?